# SPServices Get number of ListItems with the same titles

Tags: spservices

What i need is to find all list items with the same title using SPServices. I've made a CAML query from TextBox1 but have no idea what to do next. My question is: how do I change this code to accomplish my goal?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetTitleMatch() 
    {


        var Tit = $("#TextBox1").val();
       $().SPServices({
                     operation:"GetListItems",
                     listName:"CustomList",
                     async:false,
                     CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>"+
                                     "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>"+
                                     "<ViewFields>",
                     CAMLQuery:"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Tit + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
                       completefunc:function(xData,status)
                       {

                           alert($(xData.responseXML).find('[nodeName="z\\:row"]').length);
                       } 
                   });  
               }

    </script>
   <a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetTitleMatch();">click</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone cares, the complete code should loock something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function GetTitleMatch() 
{


    var Tit = $(".TextBox1").val();
    alert(Tit);
    var itemCount=0;
    var queryText = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Tit + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
    alert(queryText);
    $().SPServices({


        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "CustomList",
        async: false,

        CAMLQuery: queryText,

        completefunc: function (xData, status) {

            alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
            itemCount = $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("rs\\:data, data").attr("ItemCount");
            alert(itemCount);

            $(".TextBox3").val(itemCount);





        }
    });
           }

</script>
 <a onclick="javascript:GetTitleMatch();">click</a>
```

All I neded to do was use .attr("ItemCount")